# does pagination featuer run the query twice

Tags: yii2

Hi I am new to YII and I am now studying the user guide.. something is not clear to me in the next example, when I call to

```
$query = Country::find();
```

its gets all data from the table right? and now when I use after this:

```
$countries = $query->orderBy('name')
            ->offset($pagination->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();
```

Does its just order the result from the first query or its run a new query? (Does the query run in this code ones or twice?)

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use app\models\Country;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $query = Country::find();

        $pagination = new Pagination([
            'defaultPageSize' => 5,
            'totalCount' => $query->count(),
        ]);

        $countries = $query->orderBy('name')
            ->offset($pagination->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();

        return $this->render('index', [
            'countries' => $countries,
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: enable query profiler to see exactly whats going on

Answer (score 0):

The first query is when you call `$query->count()`, That will do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `country`
```

The second is when you call `$query->...->all()`, That will do something like

```
SELECT * FROM `country` LIMIT 0, 20
```